# Set Picture to ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I generate Picture in my code like this:

```
try {
    SVG svg = SVG.getFromResource(this, R.raw.splatter);

    SVGImageView svgImageView = new SVGImageView(this);
    svgImageView.setSVG(svg);
    svgImageView.setLayoutParams(
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    RelativeLayout layout =
            (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    layout.addView(svgImageView);

    //svg.renderViewToPicture(Integer.toString(R.id.map), layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight());
    svg.renderToPicture();
} catch (SVGParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I need set this Picture to my ImageView. How can I do this?

Comment: We are most interested in what you did so far. Not what as much as your generated picture. Can you show that?

Comment: @Whitecat, I am trying to set generated from svg file Picture object to my custom ImageView: "TouchImageView map = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.map);". Hope, you can understand me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to put the svg in res/raw? You can just reference it directly from res/drawable as you would a normal image (ie. `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.splatter)`). [This site](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) has a pretty good SVG to Android readable SVG tool.

Comment: I don't use common ImageView. My code: "TouchImageView map = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.map);". So, I have an error.

Comment: You can use BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon) to convert your drawable into a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap PicturetoDrawable(Picture picture) {
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```